# Select different data based on the result of count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simply query like this:

```
 SELECT users.id, COUNT(others.id) as c
 FROM users JOIN other ON users.id=others.user_id 
 GROUP BY users.id
```

What I would like to do is to replace the number in `c` with `''` when `c=0`.

For example, instead of a row like

```
 # I have this
 1, 0
 2, 1

 # I want c=0 replaced with ''
 1, ''  
 2, 1
```

How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: This is fairly easy but remember that the second column need to be converted to (var)char type and sorting becomes a problem. Is `NULL` acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT users.id, IF(COUNT(others.id) = 0, '', COUNT(others.id)) as c
FROM users JOIN other ON users.id=others.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [CASE or IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT t.id, CASE t.c = 0 THEN '' ELSE t.c FROM (
    SELECT users.id as id, COUNT(others.id) as c
    FROM users JOIN other ON users.id=others.user_id 
    GROUP BY users.id
 ) as t
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT users.id, IF(COUNT(others.id) > 0, COUNT(others.id), "''") as c
FROM users JOIN other ON users.id=others.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id
```

Alternatively there is COALESCE but if may not work with the 0 result

"''" (2 single quotes inside 2 double qoutes) will give you

1, '' instead of

1,